# Get pocketsphinx string

Tags: python, voice, pocketsphinx

My goal is to take the string and compare it to another string if they are the same and to perform the function in this case and open the browser but even if the strigs are the same it does nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Iterator returns you the object which you can not compare to string directly but you can print the object. It will be converted to string before printing and will look the same, but it is not comparable to a string. To figure out the type of return you can call

```
print ("test=", test,  "name=", name, "test_type=", type(test))
```

to compare you can use something like this:

```
if str(test) == name:
```

or

```
if test.hypothesis() == name:
```